# Mysql Return a row only if all its children are selected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `parent` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `true` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_test_test` (`parent`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_test_test` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `test` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I have this data:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `parent`, `true`) VALUES
('.', '.', NULL),
('active1', 'if', NULL),
('active2', 'if', NULL),
('check1', 'active1', 'case1'),
('check2', 'active1', 'case2'),
('check5', 'active1', 'case4'),
('check3', 'active2', 'case1'),
('check4', 'active2', 'case3'),
('if', '.', NULL);
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT a.`parent` FROM test a
INNER JOIN (test b) ON a.`parent` = b.`id` AND b.`parent` = 'if'
WHERE a.`true` IN ('case1','case2', 'case4')
GROUP BY a.`parent`;
```

In the result set I get `active1, active2`, but I should have only `active1` because I need the `a.parent` row only if all its children selected.

**How can I get a row, only if all its children are selected?**

Comment: +1 for preparing the schema and data in a script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` and only get those that have the same count as the number of conditions (2 in this case)

```
SELECT a.`parent` FROM test a
INNER JOIN (test b) ON a.`parent` = b.`id` AND b.`parent` = 'if'
WHERE a.`true` IN ('case1', 'case2')
GROUP BY a.`parent`
HAVING COUNT(a.`parent`) = 2;
```

In general sense, you can check the count this way:

```
SELECT a.`parent` FROM test a
INNER JOIN (test b) ON a.`parent` = b.`id` AND b.`parent` = 'if'
WHERE a.`true` IN ('case1', 'case2')
GROUP BY a.`parent`
HAVING COUNT(a.`parent`) = 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test t1 WHERE t1.`parent` = a.`parent`);
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e3bb/2)

Comment: But sometimes there are more the two cases.